# How to get error from "SQLCMD" through c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcmd

Running **SqlCmd** utility using **C#** this way :

```
// Calls the sqlcmd                
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(
  "sqlcmd", 
 @" -S VDSS218 -i D:\Ravi\Blank_Database_Creation_script.sql");

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
```

Now, If any error occurred in script while running from C# then how can fetch that SQL Exception in C#.

Comment: The error message will be in standard input or standard error.  I done it before an had issues getting information from sqlcmd.exe because it is designed to work from a windows command line that doesn't work exactly like the c# process.  My issue trying to determine when the end of a message occurred.  It was a few years ago that I wrote the code.  Windows terminates a command line with '\0' and I wasn't always getting the character.  Or I was only getting a return character and then had to send a return to get more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's declare a class for *executioning result*:

```
  public sealed class ExecutionSqlCmdResult {
    public  ExecutionSqlCmdResult(string stdOut, string stdErr, int exitCode)
      : base() {

      Out = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stdOut) ? "" : stdOut;
      Error = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stdErr) ? "" : stdErr;
      ExitCode = exitCode;
    }

    public string Out {
      get;
    }

    public string Error {
      get;
    }

    public int ExitCode {
      get;
    }
  }
```

Then we can put

```
  public static ExecutionSqlCmdResult ExecuteSqlCmd(string command) {
    ProcessStartInfo sqlCmdInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
      UseShellExecute = false,
      CreateNoWindow = true,
      WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
      RedirectStandardError = true,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      Arguments = command,
      FileName = "sqlcmd",
      StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
      StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    };

    using (Process sqlCmdProcess = new Process()) {
      sqlCmdProcess.StartInfo = sqlCmdInfo;
      sqlCmdProcess.Start();

      StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder sbErr = new StringBuilder();

      sqlCmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
        if (e.Data != null)
          sbOut.Append(e.Data);
      };

      sqlCmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
        if (e.Data != null)
          sbErr.Append(e.Data);
      };

      sqlCmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
      sqlCmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

      sqlCmdProcess.WaitForExit();

      return new ExecutionSqlCmdResult(sbOut.ToString(), sbErr.ToString(), sqlCmdProcess.ExitCode);
    }
  }
```

Usage

```
var result = ExecuteSqlCmd(@" -S VDSS218 -i D:\Ravi\Blank_Database_Creation_script.sql");

//TODO: inspect result.Out, result.Error and result.ExitCode
```

Comment: I don't think all errors cause the program to exit.  SQLCMD.exe in some cases returns a Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the event: `ErrorDataReceived`

```
proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(method);
```

See full example on MSDN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I'm seeing this handler called with null data for scripts that execute with errors as well as those that don't.